# DatagramSocket.receive() failed with an unexpected SocketException

Tags: java, socketexception

For an unconnected and bound DatagramSocket, the receive method call (with SO_TIMEOUT disabled) failed unexpectedly with the following Exception.

```
java.net.SocketException: socket closed  
 at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive0(Native Method)  
 at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.receive(PlainDatagramSocketImpl.java:136)  
 at java.net.DatagramSocket.receive(DatagramSocket.java:712)
```

Also I've not closed the socket explicitly.
This error occurred in Windows Server 2008 with JRE-6.

Even on calling DatagramSocket.close(), recreating a new DatagramSocket at the same socket address failed too.

Can you please let me know the possible cause(s) for the error?

Comment: Show us your source code that causes the Exception, please.

Answer (score 1):

I have met the same problem.
check the socket's "closed" and "connectState" fields.

```
/*
 * Connection state:
 * ST_NOT_CONNECTED = socket not connected
 * ST_CONNECTED = socket connected
 * ST_CONNECTED_NO_IMPL = socket connected but not at impl level
 */
static final int ST_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;
static final int ST_CONNECTED = 1;
static final int ST_CONNECTED_NO_IMPL = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

> java.net.SocketException: socket
>   closed

That means that *you* have closed the socket.

Comment: Thanks. But I've not closed the DatagramSocket explicitly, and that's why I say it's unexpected.

Comment: The exception doesn't agree with you, does it?